# Mediaelement.js the flash player won't hide the play button

Tags: flash, mediaelement.js

I have set the features to be empty which works fine except in the flash player. It still shows the big play button. Any ideas?
I realise I can manually hide this but I'd rather find the proper solution

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({ 
    features: [],       
    success: function (me) {                    
        me.play();           
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added a style over-ride to my page after loading the CSS.

```
<style>
   .mejs-overlay-button {display:none;}
</style>
```

Comment: Yep. The best solution to make this happen. I might file this as a bug report instead.